# Three diodes in series rectifier

Tags: diodes, rectifier, series

So, I want to make AC 220V to DC 220v rectifier. Can I use two or three diodes in series, because the reverse voltage maximum of one diode is about 60 volts?

Comment: If you put multiple identical diodes in series to increase PIV, aim for 2x voltage headroom, to allow some of them to fail short without killing the whole string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

220 V AV does not give you 220 V DC after rectification. The Peak voltage of 220 Vrms AC is 1.414 * 220 V = 311 V DC

Your diodes and smoothing capacitors should be able to handle that 311 V DC. Also the mains is only **typically** 220 V AC, at times 240 V AC or more is possible.

In practice you would use 400 V DC (or higher) rated components for a mains bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitors.

As mentioned in hatsunearu's answer using multiple diodes in series to get to the required reverse voltage rating is a **bad idea**. There will always be one diode in the series chain that is the weakest and at some point it will break through and that will also kill the other diodes. It is just not good practice.

Diodes with a high enough reverse voltage rating are available so use those.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i didn't consider the 311V after rectification

Answer (score 1):

The voltage across each diode when reverse biased in a situation like that is undefined (if they are perfectly identical, it's fine, but they probably aren't).

Play it safe and get a regular diode like a 1N4005.

Slightly related: the only time you might use redundant diodes in series is when you are building an extremely reliable product (eg. AED) where a diode failing short can cause a loss of human life.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. And for the diode recommendation too. Also do you know such a diode for an amperage about 16-20A

Comment: @user6740407 - Go to digikey.com . Use their product selection tool. Not only will it give you the specs you need, it will give a competitive price.

Comment: Did you mean 1N4004? Max reverse voltage on 1N4001 is 50V.

Comment: Oops, yeah, 1N4004.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, particularly for non-Schottky types, but your losses will be multiplied by the number of diodes. Usually we like to have 600VDC or 400VDC as an absolute minimum rating for 220VAC mains (311V peak), considering the mains will typically have transients on it.

If you put 10 60V diodes in series, each with 0.8V drop at 20A you will have losses of 320W for a full bridge (40 diodes) vs. perhaps 40W for four rectifiers with 1V forward drop.